# Get Database from firestore and using within RefreshIndicator in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Hello everyone, I am getting data from firestore . In this case ı am trying to add in RefreshIndicator() to onRefresh(); when ı am using just a data without query , ı dont see any mistake ,it work clearly like that**

```
tumGonderiler() async {
QuerySnapshot myQuerySnapshot = await akisRef.get();
setState(() {
  this.tEdilenGonderiler = myQuerySnapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
});
```

}
**but when ı am trying to query in my collection with where parameter , onRefresh() doesent work in my page , the code that does not work is as follows**

```
tumGonderiler() async {
QuerySnapshot myQuerySnapshot = await akisRef.where("ownerID", whereIn: takipEdilenKullanicilar.map((e) => e.id).toList()).get();
setState(() {
  this.tEdilenGonderiler = myQuerySnapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've changed my code a little bit untill now it's working right now you can follow from below**

```
tumGonderiler() async {
QuerySnapshot snapshot1 = await takipEdilenRef.doc(anlikKullanici!.id).collection("takipEdilenler").get();
List<tEdilen> kullaniciress = snapshot1.docs.map((doc) => tEdilen.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
setState(() {
  this.takipEdilenKullanicilar = kullaniciress;
});
QuerySnapshot myQuerySnapshot = await akisRef.where("ownerID", whereIn: takipEdilenKullanicilar.map((e) => e.id).toList()).get();
List<Gonderiler> kullanicires = myQuerySnapshot.docs.map((e) => Gonderiler.fromDocument(e)).toList();
setState(() {
  this.tEdilenGonderiler = kullanicires;
});
}


return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: baslik(context, strBaslik: "Kartlar", geriButonuYokSay: true),
  body: RefreshIndicator(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: ListView(
        children: tEdilenGonderiler,
      ),
      onRefresh: () {
        return tumGonderiler();
      }),
);
```